# I am Unable to Create Audio Blob and pass in API using React native for Speaker Recognition in Azure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I Tried Everything Convert wav file to Base64 and UTF-8 and pass but it Recognise every user, in Web it works Correctly but in react native I pass the Blob but it show Audio format not Supported

I also convert in Float32Array but did not work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.